# perl script for reading an array and put specific patterns from 1st array to second array

Tags: perl

i am trying to write a perl script where i am reading the data into an array which is an output of some command like this:

```
my @a = system "p4 changes -u";
```

now that data has been into the array @a it looks something like this:

```
change 256789 on date.. by user@workspace 'some description'
change 256788 on date.. by user@workspace 'some description'
..........................................................
...........................................................
.
.
..
...
```

there are so many lines

now what i would like to do is get the "`some description`" field of each entry into another array and then append some common text to it.
any ideas how to do it , i am relatively new to Perl so not getting much ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) executes the command but does not capture the output. To capture output you can use [backticks(`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) or the [`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) operator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @descriptions;
for (qx{p4 changes -u}) {
    chomp;
    push @descriptions, /(?<=')(.+)(?=')/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as this:

```
@b = map { /('[^']+')/; "abc $1 xyz"; } @a;
print "$_\n" for @b;
```